# Problem with apt-get on Debian 5 Lenny

Tags: debian, apt

I have to work with a Lenny VM, and I can't get apt-get to work. I already changed source.list to use archive repositories which let download some files via apt-get update, but not all. I keep getting errors such as :

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny/main/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found
```

I verified my proxy by using it in a Debian 8 VM and it works.
Is there something else I need to configure ? Where can the problem come from ?

Edit: Here is the content of `/etc/apt/source.list`:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Lenny was EOL'ed *four years ago*: no wonder it is 404'ing...

Comment: Isn't archive.debian.org supposed to give access to repositories for old distributions ?

Comment: [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/288116/edit) your question and post output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` ?

Comment: It's done now .

Comment: When you are behind a proxy, do you have apt configured to use it?

Comment: Yes it is configured in apt.conf

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny/.

There are only 3 folders

- contrib
- main
- non-free

Updates does not exist (anymore). Change your source.list so that it only contains main and optional contrib and nonfree and try again.

Comment: I edited my question, I already only use the 3 folders you listed.